# use pointer to return values from a 2d array within multiple threads

Tags: c

I am currently doing a sudoku game using multiple threads.
I set up a 2D array board[9][9] as my game board. I set up 11 threads: 1 for checking rows, 1 for checking columns, and 9 for each 3x3 subgrid.

I use this to check if digits 1-9 are properly placed:

```
void * check_row(void * n){
    numbers * input = (numbers *) n;
    int row_begin = input->row;
    int col_begin = input->column;
    for(int i=row_begin; i<9; ++i){
        int row[10] = {0};
        for (int j = col_begin; j<9; ++j){
            int value = input->board[i][j];
            if (row[value] != 0){
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                row[value] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}
```

This only checks the solution but does not display the invalid input if happens.
Can I do something about it to make it return the values of incorrect input？

Comment: What exactly in this function do you want to return? Which variable?

Comment: now the function is like a boolean function, I am trying to make it return the incorrect input if there are any. So the user will know which input is wrong in the game

Comment: Bult please tell which _exactly_ variable you want to return.

Comment: A sudoku board can have multiple invalid inputs.  There is no single value guaranteed to be wrong.  If you are running the test after a single user input, then you should already know which one is incorrect.  Otherwise, unless you're going to return an array of conflicting values, you could simply return the first one that is wrong.  You could even modify your function to pick up from a pointer to check remaining values.

Comment: sorry for not explaining this clearly. In the design, the input is a whole board containing all 81 numbers. How do I locate each incorrect number in the input? I tried &input->board[i][j] the output is -275703776 which does not seem right

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do something about it to make it return the values of incorrect input？

To return the first one that is wrong, return the address of the offending square.

```
for(int i=row_begin; i<9; ++i){
    int row[10] = {0};
    for (int j = col_begin; j<9; ++j){
        int value = input->board[i][j];
        if (row[value] != 0){
            // return (void *) 0;
            return &input->board[i][j];
        }
        else{
            row[value] = 1;
        }
    }
}
// return (void *) 1;
return (void *) 0;
```

Usage

```
numbers input;
int *result = check_row(&input);
if (result) {
  // something wrong
  ptrdiff_t offset = result - &input->board[0][0];
  int i = offset/9;
  int j = offset%9;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
} else {
  // success
}
```

---

Alternative

Add a member to `numbers` that is a `bool ok[9][9]` and have your check functions set if  something is wrong.